# 390 MHz Garage Door Opener and Raspberry Pi

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

I have a lovely Genie garage door opener (I couldn't find a model number but it looks like [this](http://www.centstome.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Genie-Garage-Door-Opener-Motor-I93-About-Nice-Home-Design-Planning-with-Genie-Garage-Door-Opener-Motor.jpg)) that I've been wanting to upgrade for a while. I'd like to open it with an RF transmitter attached to a Raspberry Pi, as I'm uncomfortable wiring the Pi directly into the opener as some tutorials suggest.

I have been using a Genie GT90-1 remote to open the garage for years, and it seems as though it should be simple to use [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/) with an RF transceiver on the right frequency. This is where I've run into trouble, because while the opener and remote appear to operate on the 390 MHz frequency (reference [one](https://www.geniedoor.com/support/faq/genie-garage-door-opener-models-and-genie-remote-listings/) and [two](http://www.genie-garage-opener.com/genie-gpt90-1-garage-door-opener-12-dip-switch-remote-same-as-gt90-1-at90-or-ct90.html)) I am having trouble finding any sort of 390 MHz transmitter/receiver that will connect properly to the Pi, most devices operating at 390 MHz appear to be Genie replacement remotes.

Is there any way I can make this project work, or is it DOA? The main obstacle seems to be finding a transmitter and receiver. Can I use something of lower/higher frequency, or some other alternative?

Thanks

Comment: The next problem is knowing WHAT to transmit on 390 MHz.  Genies intellicode was invented specifically to make it rather difficult to open a different door.   Just transmitting at 390 MHz is half the battle--the other is you must know what data to send.

Comment: @Tyson as I understand it I can use lirc to record the signal from the remote and then retransmit that.

Comment: Lirc works with infrared remotes.  Garage door remotes are RF since they must work from outside. Non-compatible technologies.

Comment: @Tyson but if I tell it it's an infrared bulb it won't know the difference. It's just for capturing and replaying the timings

Comment: Good luck, have fun.

Comment: Expanding on @Tyson response - Most modern garage door openers do not repeat their transmission patter; they have a "rolling" code specifically to prevent recording and replaying the signal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_code). This means you cannot just record the signal, but need to know the algorithm used to produce each subsequent pattern.

Comment: @Roberto my car can open the garage door. Shouldn't that be the same thing? I think this opener is older than rolling security

Comment: Garage door openers built into cars only work because the major garage door open companies licence the automakers and provide the chip to make it work.  There is two steps to programming in car remotes.  Step 1 envoles identifing which type of remote you have, in step 2 the car transmitter handshakes with the opener to initialize the rolling codes.  Without rolling codes anyone could open any garage door with very little effort.

Comment: You should tell us why you want the pi to controller the garage door.  Will the pi always be local?  or are you trying to carry the pi with you and use it as a remote?  Or are you trying to figure out how to build a burglar tool?  You are truly currently presnting this in classic [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) style.

Comment: @Tyson that Genie is older than rolling codes. You set it with DIP switches and yes you can hack them open in under 3 minutes by trying all the code combinations with a special transmitter. The newer openers have rolling codes with 2+ billion possibilities.

Comment: @Tyson I have a spare pi that I want to sit on my desk and automate my garage door, so I can open it with my phone w/o buying a new opener. All I really want from this post is a way to operate on 390 MHz RF, or to hear that it's impossible without using another remote.

Comment: If it's on 390mhz it's not older than rolling codes.. I took a quick look on mouser and the parts are available, it's not quick and easy or cheap tho.

Comment: If you want to proceed study this: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/21143b-64900.pdf

Comment: @Tyson I am 90% sure this opener does not use rolling/hopping codes. The remote has dip switches in it, and as far as I can tell dip switches and rolling codes are mutually exclusive. Is there a scenario where both could coexist in my system?

Comment: If it's in the 300-400mhz range it's code hopping.  The dip switchs provide the seed for the psuedo random number generator.  If it was older than code hopping technology it would be in the VHF range (a frequency in the 100's).  For more background read the "remote control" section of [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garage_door_opener) article.

Comment: @Tyson this is what I found. "These systems required a garage door owner to preset a digital code by switching eight to twelve DIP switches on the receiver an transmitter... [Criminals] could also make code grabbers to record and re-transmit a signal, or code scanners, that would attempt every possible combination in a short time." Retransmitting the signal sounds like exactly what I want to do. Did I misread?

Answer (score 1):

You're making this more difficult than it needs to be. Use a relay connected to the R pi. If you want it wireless, then have the relay switch the button on the remote. If you want it wired, connect the relay directly to the garage door opener to its terminals to open/close it.

Comment: I would like to avoid hardwiring it, as I said in my post. I would also like my remote to remain separate. However, I understand the complexity of this project and will probably end up buying a second remote to do as you suggest

Answer (score 0):

A second remote is probably the best wireless option, different makes an models of garage door remotes will have varying levels of difficulty interfacing with the buttons. It is almost guaranteed that  soldering will be involved.  If you are placing the Pi anywhere near the vicinity of the garage door I would wire a relay directly across the existing button.   If your PI is not going to be in the garage and assuming you have WiFi in the garage you could consider an ESP8266 with a relay controlled over WiFi with your Pi you could even use this setup to install a sensor to tell you if your door is open or closed.